# TFS - Enabling code coverage 'Profile' option in build

Tags: c++, azure-devops, tfs, code-coverage

I need to perform code coverage as part of the testing of an application within a TFS build, which I run on the Azure web portal, using VSPerfCmd.

If I was to use Visual Studio 2019, I could specify a 'Profile' setting for a specific project within the application solution, which would allow me to instrument the application to perform the coverage via the Visual Studio instrumentation tool (VSInstr.exe). However, the testing needs to be done on a full build done via TFS, not individually via Visual Studio.

I tried to set this in the MSBuild Arguments, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was enable the profile setting in Visual Studio, then checked in the changed .vcxproj file. Ran the build on TFS and instrumented the executable using vsinstr.legacy.exe, and it was fine.